# Fourier Series- solving for -cos nπ

Tags: fourier-series

When solving for $\cos n\pi$ it becomes $(-1)^n.$

However, if you have a negative in front, it becomes $-(-1)^n.$ Can you show how they get

$-(-1)^n = (-1)^{n+1}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One may observe that
$$
a^{n+1}=a\times a^n, \quad a \in \mathbb{R},
$$ giving in particular, with $a=-1$,
$$
(-1)^{n+1}=(-1)\times (-1)^n=-(-1)^n.
$$